# How test doubles, help me test a Unit that interacts with a SOAP Webservice via SoapClient

Tags: php, testing, phpunit, stub

I recently started my journey on testing in php. I am having a hard time getting my head around how to test external services and how a stub will help me assure that the method being testing really behaves as the test promises.

Following example is as taken from the code im unable to understand how to test. I have only included the construct and method in question.

```
class SoapWrap {


        const WDSL_URL = 'http://traindata.dsb.dk/stationdeparture/Service.asmx?WSDL';

    /**
    *   The WDSL/SOAP Client
    *   @access private
    *   @var \SoapClient $Client
    */
    private $Client; // SOAP client.


    /**
    *   Sets up \SoapClient connection.
    *   @throws \SoapFault upon SOAP/WDSL error.
    */
    public function __construct( \SoapClient $SoapClient )
    {

        try 
        {

            $this->Client = $SoapClient;

        }
        catch( \SoapFault $SoapFault )
        {

            throw $SoapFault;
        }
    }


    /** 
    *   Gets all stations and filters if a filter is passed.
    *
    *   As DSB SOAP service only allows to get all stations 
    *   a filter can be used narrow down the results. 
    *   @param \DSBPHP\Filters\BaseFilter $StationFilte
    *   @return Array with station value objects.
    */
    public function getStations( \DSBPHP\Filters\FilterInterface $StationFilter = null )
    {
        // DSB soap service inforces only method for getting all stations...
        $stations = $this->Client->GetStations()->GetStationsResult->Station;

        if($StationFilter !== null) 
            return $StationFilter->run($stations);

        // return all trains
        return $stations;
    }
}
```

In the following in test, i have tried to insure that the test do not actully use the SoapClient nor the SoapWrap as it uses the SoapClient as dependecy. The SoapWrap double is because of the ->GetStations call on the soap service inside the getstations() in the code above.

```
class SoapWrapTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {


    private $SoapWrap;


    public function setUp()
    {

        $SoapClient = $this ->getMockBuilder('\SoapClient')
                            ->setMethods(['__construct'])
                            ->disableOriginalConstructor()
                            ->getMock();

        $this->SoapWrap = $this ->getMockBuilder('\DSBPHP\App\SoapWrap')
                                ->setMethods(['__construct', 'getStations'])
                                ->disableOriginalConstructor()
                                ->setConstructorArgs([$SoapClient])
                                ->getMock();
    }


    public function testGetStationsReturnsArray()
    {

        $this->SoapWrap ->expects($this->once())
                        ->method('getStations')
                        ->will($this->returnValue([]));

        $stations = $this->SoapWrap->getStations();
        $this->assertInternalType('array', $stations);
    }
}
```

I do not understand how this insures that my real soap service SoapWrap actully returns an array, and how i should test this.
As i understand it, my test should fail at first, until i implement the code that makes it pass. But with this test, which most be obviously wrong, it always passes. Which takes away any value that i can understand from the test.

I hope you can help me with some examples of how to really test such method.

Comment: @skrilled I think my test methods passes because i assert the internal type to be an array. The pickle is that the getStations returns exactly what i tell it to, in this case an array. So how does this test help me validate anything?

Comment: an empty array is still an array. maybe i'm misunderstanding your question? you want it to fail when what happens?

Comment: I make a stub, i will tell it what to return. In this case an empty array. This is also what i am testing in the test (testGetStationsReturnsArray). So it makes good sense for the test to pass. What i do not get, is how this test help me or how i should have gone about testing.

Comment: @QuackQuacker: You stubbed / mocked the wrong. Don't mock the unit under test, instead mock the it's collaborators (dependencies) so that you test the units code (and not that stubbing/mocking is working).

Comment: @hakre yea this makes sense too. Instead i should make sure that all calls to the SoapClient inside the tested unit is mocked, if i understand it correct. Thanks few lines have been of tremendous help

Comment: No, you don't need to check the internal behavior, for the Unit test of `SoapWrap` you are only concerned about it's public interface. That is uses `SoapClient` internally is only a detail you need to deal with for the stubbing/mocking, however not for testing internal behavior of `SoapWrap`.

Comment: Just found this somewhat related Q&A probably worth to cross-link: [PHPUnit: How to mock a function on a class?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18482362/367456) - It explains for the cases where dependency injection is not yet used, that it needs to be added to allow proper mocking for tests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not 100% grasp the example in your question, however if I understand it right you want to test the `SoapWrap` unit and it has `SoapClient` as a collaborator.

Now when you create a test if `SoapWrap::getStations()` returns an array - which it actually always does - the test will always pass. So for your first question about the failed test until it is implemented (as in Test Driven Development (TDD): Test Fails (Red); Write as little code as only needed until it passes (Yellow (or: Green)); Refactor the code (Green (or: Blue))), but you did it the wrong way. You must have written the test before writing the code, e.g. the first time you call the test, PHPunit should crash with a fatal error that the `SoapWrap` class is not found and can not be instantiated because so far it has not been written.

So delete it now and try to forget the code you've done so far, re-run the test to see it fail and then write it new.

Ensure you've unit-tested the class of `$StationFilter` before that, too.

For the second part of your question about the mocking: You mock the collaborators, here most likely the `SoapClient::GetStations()` method. This will spare you to actually run the remote request via SOAP. That easy it is already. You mock the collaborators to test the unit.

Comment: Yes, this makes sense! Thanks. I understand that when the class is missing, the code actully does exactly what it should. Thanks alot,
Can you give me any insight if i need to write any test to actully test the actual soap service or if such test should not be part of unittests.

Comment: The SOAP Service is an external system. It's not your job to test it, so this is not part of your Unit tests. However you should test what happens if the remote service gives some exception like with a failure, e.g. when down. Try to find out what happens then, mock this scenario and try it out. That way you can more easily design for failure which will make your software more robust. Also think about how you can monitor the remote services so that you gather some data how reliable it is and how likely you need to decouple the remote service. At least document your requirements for operations.

Comment: Thanks for giving me a answer to all of my questions.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help you to try out the web service that you created,  you can try to simulate the data transfered with this apps. Check here http://www.soapui.org/

Thanks&Regards,
Janitra Panji

Comment: Hi Janitra, thanks for the link. I did not make the webservice, and i am looking for phpunit/mockery solutions and most of all an understanding to my questions.